# $\ast$-homomorphism and two-sided ideals of unitarization $C^\ast$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, ideals, operator-algebras

We work with the unitization of $C^\ast$-algebra. I.e.
$C^\ast$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ with norm $\|\cdot\|$. Let $\tilde{\mathcal{A}}=\mathcal{A}\oplus \mathbb{C}$ as a vector space. We endow it with multiplication and involution,

$$(a,\lambda)\cdot (b,\mu):=(ab+\lambda b+\mu a,\lambda \mu)$$
and
$$(a,\lambda)^\ast:=(a^\ast,\bar{\lambda})$$

I managed to prove that this is a $\ast$-algebra. Now I have some questions because I want to understand this example.

1. We denote $\omega:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ by the map $\omega(a):=(a,0)$. I want to show that this is a $\ast$-homomorphism, i.e. it is linear and so on. The example does not show anything regarding $\ast$-homomorphism, but my attempt: Let $a,b\in\mathcal{A}$ then $\omega(a+b)=(a+b,0)=(a,0)+(b,0)=\omega(a)+\omega(b)$. Is it true?
2. I readed about two side ideals in my book. Is it true that $\omega(\mathcal{A})$ is a two-sided ideal in $\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$? If so, how come?

**Definition:** A (two-sided) ideal $J$ in a Banach algebra $\mathscr{A}$ is a subspace of $A$
with the property that $A \in \mathscr{A}$ and $S \in J$ implies $AS \in J$ and $SA \in J$.

Is this definition the right one to use? If so, then I will try to do the part "$AS \in J$" if anyone can give an example of the other part $SA \in J$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the fact that $\omega$ is a $*$-homomorphism simply follows from the fact that $\omega(\mathcal{A}) = \mathcal{A} \times \{0\}$ inherits the $*$-algebra structure from $\mathcal{A}$. By definition, we have
$$\omega(\alpha a + \beta b) = (\alpha a + \beta b, 0) = \alpha (a,0) + \beta (b,0) = \alpha \omega(a) + \beta \omega(b),$$
$$\omega(ab) = (ab,0) = (a,0)(b,0) = \omega(a)\omega(b),$$
$$\omega(a^*) = (a^*,0) = (a,0)^*.$$

$\omega(\mathcal{A}) = \mathcal{A} \times \{0\}$ is indeed a two-sided ideal in $\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$. For $(a,0),(b,0) \in \mathcal{A} \times \{0\}$ and $(c,\lambda) \in \tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ we have
$$\alpha (a,0) + \beta (b,0) = (\alpha a + \beta b,0) \in \mathcal{A} \times \{0\},$$
$$(a,0)(c,\lambda) = (ac+ \lambda a,0) \in \mathcal{A} \times \{0\}, \qquad (c,\lambda)(a,0) = (ca + \lambda a, 0) \in \mathcal{A} \times \{0\}.$$

Comment: Nice explanation! Thank you. I might return if I have more ideas/questions. I will now read it and understand it.